# Rails Active Storage in rails api from parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have the following in my parameters that comes from a client. And I want to use active storage to store it. I have configured the user model and created the tables for active storage. How do I extract the following and store it?

```
"user_pic"=>[{"rawFile"=> 
   {"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/5d1f0bc6-efc6-458b-a297- 
     94f26aa1e7d5"}, "src"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/5d1f0bc6-efc6- 
      458b-a297-94f26aa1e7d5", "title"=>"avatar.png"
}]
```

Comment: why do your URLs have `blob:` in front of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  has_one_attached :pic
end
```

inside controller:

```
pic_params = params["user_pic"].first
user.pic.attach(
  io: open(pic_params['src'])
  filename: pic_params['title']
)
```